# Why is my neovim popup floating window border line broken?

Tags: window, border, floating, neovim

whichever floating window like vim-floaterm or vim-fzf, border line of each is broken like this, so i tried setting like:

```
set guifont=SauceCodePro:h14
set guifontwide=SauceCodePro:h14
set ambiwidth=double
set encoding=utf-8
set termencoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

none of them above can solve my problem, so what the heck is wrong? And you can see that border of each floating window is incomplete and weird in pics below! Can someone help, I really apreciate!

[image]

[image]